# Returning an exact match from a JavaScript array using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I have an array of people and want to filter on some criteria, in this case I want to search for a "male" which should return just one result however with this set I'm getting everything back because the regular expression is capturing female as well.

I tried matching on "\bmale" or "/\bmale" but didn't get anything back. I know I need to use a word boundary but for some reason it's not working out.

```
var people = [["Adelaide", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Ada", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Amanda", 1, "yes", "female"],
           ["Wolf", 3, "no", "male"],
           ["Rhonda", 1, "no", "female"]];

var isMale = function(x) {
  var myMatch = new RegExp("male");
  var test = String(x).match(myMatch);
  return String(x).match(myMatch);
}


var filteredArray=people.filter(isMale);

document.writeln(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Just remind me one more time: Why are you using a Regex for this?

Comment: This could be done much more simply: `var filteredArray = people.filter(function(itm) { return itm[2] == "male"; });`

Comment: @Joseph Silber - because it's convenient to filter a multidimensional array since that's what a match() returns. Unless there's an easier way?

Comment: @firedrawndagger - take a look at my answer, then come back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't use a regular expression when it's not necessary!!!**

Use this instead:

```
var people = [
    ["Adelaide", 2, "yes", "female"],
    ["Ada", 2, "yes", "female"],
    ["Amanda", 1, "yes", "female"],
    ["Wolf", 3, "no", "male"],
    ["Rhonda", 1, "no", "female"]
];

var filteredArray = people.filter(function(el){
    return el[3] == 'male';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XRHtZ/ (check your console)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just match against `^male`, which would be the start of the line, immediately followed by "male"?

Answer (score 2):

The word "female" contains the word "male" :-)

You filter should really just look at the simple value of the last element in the component sub-arrays. No need to use a regex; just compare:

```
return  x[3] === "male";
```

That's really all your "isMale()" function needs to do.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the beginning/end of string characters would be more appropriate here:

```
var myMatch = new RegExp('^male$');
```

Comment: And really, you could just do `var myMatch = /^male$/;` for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only match items that are exactly "male", then just compare directly:

```
function isMale(x) {
    return(x == "male");
}
```

No need to use a regular expression for an exact match.